# Would like blank cells to show value of adjacent cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I made a budgeting spreadsheet and have a "current" and "ideal" column. Current is what I'm spending now. Ideal is what I'd like to be spending. In some cases the "ideal" number is the same as "current."

What I would like to do is put in "ideal" values where necessary and otherwise just give the value of the "current" cell.

For example:

| Expense | Current | Ideal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Rent | 3000 |  |
| Vacation | 1000 | 5000 |

I don't plan to move so my rent would, ideally, still be 3000. But I'd like to spend more on vacation. So what I'd want is a formula for the ideal row that would show the value of the adjacent cell if the ideal cell is blank. I suppose it would be something like this:

```
if (isblank(this_cell), offset(this_cell, 0, -1))
```

So far I can't even find a way to reference the current cell at all - I found suggestions but they all gave me a circular reference error. And I don't know if offset is the best function but I've been googling around and it seems like a possibility.

Can this be done, and if so, how?

Comment: You need AppScript to do that. By formula you can't.

Comment: Would it work for you to just set the cell to the value next to it (as a default) and then overwrite that formula with the actual value when you wish?

Comment: This can't be done using built-in functions / formulas. You might do something close by using Google Apps Script. Start by reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets.